# Getting error when i add jInternalFrame into jDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, awt

When i try to add internal frame into jdesktoppane i got error shown below. I took a glance on several forum for solution bu didn't get anything helpful. Please tell me where I am mistaking.

Error :java.lang.NullPointerException

My code is below :
private JInternalFrame CreateMWindow() {

```
        String windowName = "Earth View";

        JInternalFrame iframe = new JInternalFrame(windowName, true, true, true, true);

        iframe.setBounds(25,25,200, 100);
       iframe.setSize(600, 350);
        iframe.setLocation(0, 0);

        try{
            iframe.addInternalFrameListener((InternalFrameListener) this);
            iframe.setVisible(true);
            desktop_pane.add(iframe);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error :"+e);
        }
        try
        {
            iframe.setSelected(true);
        }
        catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e)
        {
        }
        return iframe;
}
```

Comment: where is your definition for `desktop_pane`?

Comment: thanks..i was lacking there...but even after initializing desktop_pane internal frame is not getting showed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you initialized your JDesktopPane field `desktop_pane`? I don't think so. You have to initialized it.

```
desktop_pane = new JDesktopPane();
```